# Как узнать, что SQL запрос выполнен?

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день.
Есть запрос

```
        $id= urldecode($_GET["id"]);
        $value= urldecode($_GET["value"]);
        $property= urldecode($_GET["property"]);

        $this->Vipolnit_Zapros("UPDATE students SET $property='$value' WHERE id='$id';");
-------------------- 
public function ConnectDB()
    {
$result = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);  // настройки Базы данных
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo 'Ошибка подключения (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
    return false;
    }
else{
    $result->set_charset("utf8");
    return $result;
}
    }

    public function Vipolnit_Zapros($ZAPROS)
    {
        $conn = $this->ConnectDB();
        $data = array();
        if($conn->connect_error) 
            return 'false';
        else
            $result = $conn->query("$ZAPROS");
            if(!$result)
                {
                    echo 'Error' . mysql_error();
                    exit(); 
                }
        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $data[]= $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return 'false';
    }
------------
```

Как мне узнать, были ли изменены свойства, и если да, то написать `echo "true";` либо `echo "false";`, если не было затронутых строк?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.exec.php). Не совсем понятно, из примера, как Вы выполняете запрос.

Comment: Фактически запрос выполняется всегда, но иногда может в холостую, когда изменённых результатов нет